# Remove author bio from posts of a specific author

Tags: author

I am trying to find how all posts of a specific author will appear without the author box, while all the others authors posts will have their author boxes.

Can somebody help me with this?

Comment: How do your show the author information? Add the code to your question.

Answer (score 1):

In my theme with raw codes, Post Meta Data are shown like:

```
<div class="entry-meta">
   <span class="meta-prep meta-prep-author"><?php _e('By ', 'your-theme'); ?></span>
   <span class="author vcard"><a class="url fn n" href="<?php echo get_author_posts_url( false, $authordata->ID, $authordata->user_nicename ); ?>" title="<?php printf( __( 'View all posts by %s', 'your-theme' ), $authordata->display_name ); ?>"><?php the_author(); ?></a></span>
</div><!-- .entry-meta -->
```

It displays the meta data like:

```
Post Content here like Lorem Ipsum is simply
dummy text of the printing and typesetting
industry.
____________________________________________
by Author_name
```

In my case, you can simply put a conditional tag like:

```
<?php if( !is_author( 'author_nickname' ) ) : ?>
   <div class="entry-meta">
      ...
   </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

**Note:** I enabled the meta-box for all author, except someone. I put the `author_nickname` here, you can put the `author_id` too. Check the Codex:

> **Codex: [Function Reference:is_author()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_author)**

Comment: It didn't worked. Perhaps because my theme is more complicated. Here is the code for bio box in single.php. Please have a look again: <div id="authorbox">

<div id="authorimg">
<?php $authoravatar = get_avatar( get_the_author_meta('email'), $size = '80'); ?>
<?php if ($authoravatar !== NULL) { ?>
<?php echo $authoravatar; ?>
<?php } ?>

</div>

<div id="authorbioname">
<h2><?php the_author_posts_link(); ?></h2>
</div>

<div id="authorbio">
<p><?php the_author_meta('description'); ?></p>
</div>

<div id="authorsocial">

<?php $facebook = get_the_author_meta( 'facebook' ); ?>
....
</div>
</div>

Comment: Have you tried embracing your parent div with the code I suggestd, like this: `<?php if( is_author() ) : ?><div id="authorbox">...</div><?php endif; ?>`?

Answer (score 1):

First of all I'd recommend to use a child theme and leave behind the original theme, this way you wouldn't lose any customizations when updating your theme.

Then, if you're actually using a child theme, just copy to your child theme directory this `single.php`, and wrap the author `div` with this:

```
if ( get_post_field( 'post_author', get_queried_object_id() ) != $author_id) :
...
endif;
```

... where `$author_id` is the ID of the author you want to hide the block.

The other way depends on how works your theme, if the author `div` is handle by a function, look for it in the `*functions.php` of your theme, and copy it to your `functions.php` *(in your child theme directory)* and do the mentioned modification.